# If GPS cannot fetch location, switch to network in Android

Tags: android, networking, gps

I am trying to get location based on GPS or network but the problem is that if I take based on GPS location it takes lot of time to fetch the location details. Hence I would like implement a method where if GPS signal is very low fetch location using network provider. How do I determine the GPS signal? if do there is problem with this? GPS signal is always low even in open sky and hence it would always get to network provider?

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you polling the location with LocationManager.GetLastKnownLocation, or are you getting updates asynchronously via requestLocationUpdates?

For the first, query for the location with the GPS_PROVIDER.  If it returns null, then query for NETWORK_PROVIDER

If you're getting notifications, request both.  Then you can implement onStatusChanged to tell when the GPS is available or not, and ignore network updates if it is, or use them if not (the location object tells you what the provider was).

Comment: I am using requestLocationUpdates but not asynchronously. I am calling this inside a button click. Something like this: 

locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5,locationListener);

Then I call the listener. 

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
{
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed:" + loc.getLatitude() + loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

I am not sure where do I check how to get if GPS data is null then ntw

Comment: If you're calling it at all, its asycnhronous.  The requestLocationUpdates will call your listener every so often until canceled.  So if there is no GPS synch it will never be called.  You need to call requestLocationUpdates twice, once for NETWORK_PROVIDER, once for GPS_PROVIDER.  Then you'll be called whenever either updates. Just ignore the network updates if a GPS update came recently.

Comment: So two listeners: one for GPS and One for Network and for ignoring network update if required: how do I detect if GPS provider has got it or Network provider has got. Shall I use a timer?

Comment: The best way is to override the onStatusChanged of the GPS listener and see whether GPS is available or not.  It won't be available unless it actually has a lock.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Adding lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll); it will start fetching the gps using networ. Using location.getProvider() you should be able to differentiate to know whether its gps or network.